# Immersive app with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, startactivityforresult, android-immersive

I have a fullscreen, immersive-sticky activity A, which works fine due to: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html.

From there I want to take a picture using `startActivityForResult()` as in: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

However, before leaving A into the system camera app, the system bar appears shortly in my app, which is considerably irritating. How can I prevent this?

Best would be to prevent the system bar in the camery app as well, but I think this is futile.

Comment: Have you tried if the same thing happens with getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: No behavior change, I already set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`  in the `Manifest.xml`

Comment: I meant instead of using immersive, using flags

Comment: Fullscreen is not exactly what I need, I also want to fade out the (software) System Bar (e.g. on S8)